# How to handle addListenerForSingleValue properly after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm using Firebase from a long time and I really appreciate its flexibility to fetch some data from its realtime database with low effort. However, I'm having some problems on handling the result of the call of addListenerForSingleValueEvent.
Every time some UI operation has to be performed after it returns my application crashes if onSaveInstanceState has already been called.
There is any way to abort the operation during onPause() the same way we can do with addValueEventListener?

I know that a solution could be checking if onSaveInstanceState has already been called but all solution I tried seems to be unreliable.
I try checking for methods like:

```
isAdded()
isVisible()
isFinishing()
```

both for fragments and activities.

An example of my attemps is:

```
dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if(isAdded && isVisible && activity?.isFinishing == false){
            GenericMessageDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.generic_error_title), errorMessage).show(activity?.supportFragmentManager, "ed")
    }
}
```

Sometimes this exception is thrown

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: An `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` cannot be removed. But it is supposed to fire very shortly after you attach it, so typically it will be within the same lifecycle of the activity. Where are you attaching the listener? Can you detect that the activity is (about to be) paused there?

Comment: Consider just enqueueing the operation while you're after onPause, and run the command after onResume -- currently I use https://github.com/Zhuinden/command-queue for this